# AWS Glue unable to access input data set

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I have a dataset registered in Glue / Athena, call it `my_db.table`. I'm able to query it via Athena and everything generally seems to be in order.

I'm trying to use this table in a Glue job, but am getting the following fairly opaque error message:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o54.getCatalogSource.
: java.lang.Error: No classification or connection in my_db.table
```

This would appear to indicate that Glue can't see the catalog entry for my table, or can't use the information in that entry, but I don't have any further visibility than that.

Has anyone experience with this error and what might be causing it?

Comment: Have you tried creating table with Glue Crawler? In my project only the tables created by crawler work properly with Jobs. Also the tables generated by Glue Crawler are readable by Athena

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message actually describes the problem well - there was no classification for the table being queried.

Tables created via Glue are registered with a Classification - `csv`, `parquet`, `orc`, `avro`, `json`. See [Creating Tables Using Athena for AWS Glue Jobs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-best-practices.html#schema-etl-tables).

The table I created 'manually' via Athena did not have a classifcation. See the below screenshot from the Glue 'tables' page.

[image]

The solution is easy: at the end of the `CREATE TABLE` script user must append a `classification` property like so

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_db.my_table (
  `id` int,
  `description` string 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ',',
  'collection.delim' = 'undefined',
  'mapkey.delim' = 'undefined'
) LOCATION 's3://my_bucket/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('classification'='csv');
```

Now the table has a classification within the Glue interface and is accessible via a Glue job.

Comment: This did not work for me - adding the 'classification' tblproperty had no effect on whether or not I could read the table via `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog`. Only tables created by the Glue crawler seemed to work. I even tried making all the properties of my Athena table match exactly those of the Glue crawler table and it still wouldnt work. Still trying to find a solution...

Comment: Interesting - the above didnt work for a CSV table but it *did* work for a parquet table. Hmm...

Comment: It does not seem to work for Views either, fyi -- I'm hoping to pull data from a view in an ETL job, if anyone has managed to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add the classification in the table you've created. To add it via UI follow these steps:

1. Go to the table in glue:

[image]

2. click on Edit Table and add it as shown in image:
   [image]